# Chrome webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to utilize local FS in Chrome.
The first thing I do - request filesystem quota.
The code below worked only once, making Chrome to show confirmation.
But after that this code does nothing: no alert is displayed.
What is wrong with this code?

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;     
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota( 
            window.PERSISTENT,
            fsize,
            function( bytes ) {
                alert( "Quota is available: " + bytes );
            },
            function( e ) {
                alert( "Error allocating quota: " + e );
            }

);
```

Comment: You should use `window.requestFileSystem.requestQuota...` not `window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota...`. If not then the first line is pointless ;-).

Comment: Scratch that. The first line is pointless in this situation. Though you might want to try `window.storageInfo = window.storageInfo || window.webkitStorageInfo;` and wrap the call in some `if` so that it don't shout with errors in other browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the user has granted access to `fsize` quota, the browser won't reprompt them.
Your success callback will be called without the info bar. The only way to see
it again (for testing), is to request a larger `fsize`.

You could also try 'Clear browsing data' in settings to see if that resets things.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/:

"Once the user has granted permission, there's no need to call requestQuota() in the future (unless you wish to increase your app's quota). Subsequent calls for equal or lesser quota are a noop."

NB: This implies there's no way for an app to release quota that it no longer needs.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting quota for testing

When you are testing storage in your app, you might want to clear the stored data so that you can test quota management afresh in your app. To do so:

1. Enter chrome://settings/cookies in the omnibox (the address bar).
2. Search for your app.
3. Select your app.
4. Click the X on the right side of the highlighted selection.

https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage